# To which value does $\lambda \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left[\left(1-\lambda \right)^j \right]$ converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $\lambda$ is smllaer than 1 and greater than 0. Then what does $\lambda \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left[\left(1-\lambda \right)^j \right]$ converge to? If this depends on specific range of values, can anyone give what these ranges are?

Comment: Do you know the sum of the geometric series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k$$ for $\lvert q\rvert< 1$?

Comment: Oh yeah.. Thanks for reminding me that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a geometric series.  It converges to 
$$\lambda\left({1\over 1-(1-\lambda)}\right) = 1,$$
provided $\lambda < 1$.  If $\lambda = 1$ it converges to $0$, if you 
disregard the $0^0$ and $1$ otherwise.

Comment: Caveat:  if $\lambda = 1$, you have an annoying $0^0$.

Comment: Note that the question excludes $\lambda\in\{0,1\}$, i.e., $\lambda\in(0,1)$ (exclusive interval).

Answer (score 1):

It’s just a geometric series with ratio $1-\lambda$:

$$\lambda\sum_{j\ge 0}(1-\lambda)^j=\frac\lambda{1-(1-\lambda)}=1\;,$$

provided that $|1-\lambda|<1$, i.e., that $0<\lambda<2$.

Comment: You are taking $0^0 = 1$.  In this case, it's cricket.

Comment: @ncmathsadist: There are very few contexts in which I would not take $0^0=1$.

Comment: In this case I think you are right.  It seems to be one of those little conventions with power series.